# Plotting time series in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time-series

here's an example of my data:

```
df = {
    'veh_ID': [102, 102],
    'Trip_ID': [1, 2],
    'Trip_Start': ['08:00', '11:00'],
    'Trip_end': ['10:00', '11:10'],
    'Travel distance': [12, 1]
}
```

I'm trying to plot the cumulative distance vs time, to show on one line for this vehicle id, the trip start and ends and in between the stop time with flat line showing no slope in distance.

this is what i tried:

```
df.sort_values(by='Trip_Start', inplace=True)
df['Cumulative Distance'] = df['Travel distance'].cumsum()
plt.plot(df['Trip_Start'], df['Cumulative Distance'], marker='o', label='Start', color='blue')
plt.plot(df['Trip_End'], df['Cumulative Distance'].shift(-1), marker='o', label='End', color='red')
plt.plot(df[['Trip_End', 'Trip_Start']].values.T.flatten(), df['Cumulative Distance'].shift(-1).repeat(2), color='green', linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative Distance (km)')
plt.title('Journey Plot')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But this is the output instead of one continous line with these points:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mvJZ.png)

Comment: I don't get exactly what you want, can you clarify it a little bit. there are 3 plot functions called in your code, that's why you see 3 lines in the resulted plot

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Yes, I noticed that, but I don't know any other way  to plot all these points on one line:
I tried 'plt.plot(df['Trip_Start'], df['Cumulative Distance'], marker='o', label='Start/End', color='blue')' but it just plots the start times..

Comment: Can you draw the desired plot so that I can understand exactly what you mean? I'm not so sure if I know exactly what you need to draw

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Have updated the image, so it just shows for trip_start: at 8:00 corresponding distance 12 which should be 0 then at 10:00 the 12 and a horizontal line till 11:00 then to 13 at 11:10 (Hope this clarifies it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use pandas, but I made this code that achieves what you want. If it doesn't fit your needs, I hope it helps you understand the logic of what you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = {
    'veh_ID': [102, 102],
    'Trip_ID': [1, 2],
    'Trip_Start': ['08:00', '11:00'],
    'Trip_end': ['10:00', '11:10'],
    'Travel distance': [12, 1]
}


def plot_trip(df):
    # Get numeric time values from Trip_Start and Trip_end
    start = [int(x.split(':')[0]) + int(x.split(':')[1]) / 60 for x in df['Trip_Start']]
    end = [int(x.split(':')[0]) + int(x.split(':')[1]) / 60 for x in df['Trip_end']]

    # Create timeline:
    time = []
    if len(start) == len(end):
        for i in range(len(start)):
            time.append(start[i])
            time.append(end[i])

    # Define distances:
    distance = []
    index = 0
    if len(start) == len(df['Travel distance']):
        for i in range(len(time)):
            if i == 0:
                distance.append(0)
            elif i % 2 == 0:
                distance.append(distance[-1])
            else:
                distance.append(df['Travel distance'][int(i / 2)]+distance[-1])

    # Plot
    plt.plot(time, distance)
    plt.show()
```

To keep using the times in string format you could also create points on a plot and simply connect all points, but I don't have a solution for this idea